# Code to draw works in button click event but not in form load

Tags: vb.net, buttonclick, form-load

why can I run the following code faultless under a button even but not under the form load even?

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\pos.xml")

    If line.Contains("<POS>") = True Then

        Dim tagless As String = StripTags(line)

        Dim parts As String() = tagless.Split(New Char() {","})
        Dim XVAL As Decimal = parts(0)
        Dim YVAL As Decimal = parts(1)

        'paint markers...
        Dim myBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red))
        Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
        formGraphics = Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, New Rectangle(XVAL - 35, YVAL - 35, 70, 70))

        myBrush.Dispose()
        formGraphics.Dispose()

    End If
Next
```

Here is the striptag function if requierd...

```
    Function StripTags(ByVal html As String) As String
    ' Remove HTML tags.
    Return Regex.Replace(html, "<.*?>", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What happens?  The stuff you draw wont persist that way: drag something across the form or minimize and it will disappear

Comment: ***what errors are you getting if any?*** Where is it not working?

Comment: You should do all your drawing in the paint event of the form. At form load, the form is still loading and so there will be a paint even that occurs after load that will remove everythign you have drawn

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict

Comment: It gives no errors nothing happens when i try and trigger it with the form-load event..under a button clicked event it works perfectly

Comment: Ohh I didnt even notice that you could do somthing with the arrows sorry

Comment: No problem...upvoting answers and questions which help others know how useful the content is.  You can/should upvote anything you see that helps - not just answers you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to draw is hardly ever with `CreateGraphics`.  This will draw something that does not persist.  When the area is invalidated such as the form is minimized or another form/app is dragged over it, your shapes will disappear.

You should also turn on `Option Strict`.  There are numerous type errors in the code.  For instance there is no `Rectangle` constructor which takes a `Decimal`.  That is not even the right Class for non integers, but `RectangleF` doesn't take a Decimal either.

---

The core problem is that the form is shown *at the end* of the form load event. So, your code is running/drawing before the form is visible and nothing is shown.  Even if the form *was* already showing, whatever you draw would not be retained if the user minimized the form or moved another window across it.

```
' form level list to store the data
Private XY As New List(Of PointF)       ' pts
```

Then in form load event, read the data and add to the list

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("...")
    If line.Contains("<POS>") = True Then
        Dim tagless As String = StripTags(line)

        '                                      c required under Option Strict
        Dim parts As String() = tagless.Split(New Char() {","c})
        ' convert values to single. create a PointF
        Dim ptF As New PointF(Convert.ToSingle(parts(0)), Convert.ToSingle(parts(1)))
        ' add to list
        XY.Add(ptF)
   End If
Next
```

The next thing that happens should be the form being shown and the paint event invoked.  The data is used in the Paint Event:

```
Dim rectF As RectangleF
Using myB As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red))
    For Each ptF As PointF In XY
        rectF = New RectangleF(ptF.X - 35, ptF.Y - 35,
                                70, 70)

        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myB, rectF)
    Next
End Using
```

If you have other code to add Point data, like a Button click, after you add, change or remove data, use `Invalidate` to force a redraw: `Me.Invaludate()` is you are drawing to the form, or `PictureBox1.Invalidate()` if you are drawing over a control.

The lesson is that now, every time the form needs to be repainted, your shapes will be redrawn as well.